# Changing Symfony2's default templating engine to PHP

Tags: symfony, twig, template-engine

I know how to use PHP templates by adding the PHP templating engine to app/config/config.yml:

```
  templating:      { engines: ['php','twig'] }
```

... and I know how to change the default templating engine in a particular controller by adding an annotation:

```
/**
 * @Template(engine="php")
 */
```

... but is there a way to change the default for the entire app, rather than doing it controller by controller? I couldn't find any documentation/discussion about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

Simply disable twig:

```
# app/config/config.yml
    framework:
        templating:    { engines: ['php'] }
```